# Java 8 Lambda Replacement for Apache Commons CollectionsUtils.select

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, apache-commons, java-stream

I have the following code using Apache Commons lib:

```
public static List<Address> addressesHasType(final List<Address> addresses, final AddressType... types) {
    return (List<Address>) CollectionUtils.select(addresses, new Predicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(final Object object) {
            boolean isContains = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < types.length && !isContains; i++) {
                isContains = ((Address) object).getTypes().contains(types[i]);
            }
            return isContains;
        }
    });
}
```

I trying to make to refactor it to use only lambda and Java 8 without Apache Commons lib, something like this:

```
List<Address> addressList = addresses.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getTypes().contains(types)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the list become empty in the end. I tried using findFirst() to but it does not returns a List but a Optional object.

```
addressList2 = addresses.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getTypes().contains(types)).findFirst();
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two nested loops in your code. The transformation of the outer loop looks good, but the inner loop is missing in the transformed code. Let's take a look at the inner loop first:

```
boolean evaluate(Address address, AddressTypes... types) {
    for (AddressType type : types) {
        if (address.getTypes().contains(type)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using a stream and a method reference, the implementation looks as follows:

```
boolean evaluate(Address address, AddressTypes... types) {
    return Arrays.stream(types).anyMatch(address.getTypes()::contains);
}
```

Combining this transformation with your first approach, the result looks as follows:

```
public static List<Address> addressesHasType(List<Address> addresses, AddressType... types) {
    return addresses.stream()
        .filter(a -> Arrays.stream(types).anyMatch(a.getTypes()::contains))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first predicate uses `contains(types[i])`. Your second uses `contains(types)`.

So they don't do the same thing at all. The second predicate checks that the types contains the array of AddressType `types`, instead of checking that it contains one of the elements of the array of AddressType `types`.